# Help, need example payment application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, payment

Please provide me any link or application which provides payment functionality on iPhone...

for example - if the user wants to send mail from the app, i need to charge money for it..

Thanks for any help

Comment: Payement Functionality ??? what do you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe following articles will help you:

- [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [iPhone Tutorial – In-App Purchases](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/)
- [Things I learned implementing my first InAppPurchase](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/02/things-i-learned-implementing-my-first-inapppurchase/)
- [In App Purchases: A Full Walkthrough](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

Comment: hi..can you give me a sample application in which i can understand how they proceed the payment process

Comment: @barbgal: I added a link for implementation. May be it will help you.

Comment: @barbgal: Wrong link was posted. Fixed now.

Comment: @navneed: can you pls explain me in words how the payemnt process is done..actually what i want to know is when user sends a mail how the payment is charged.i mean how we get user;s money to reach us...

Comment: @barbgal: Above links have answers of most of your questions.