# How can I take payments from iTunes in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, itunes

What are the steps for taking iTunes payments?

I have an application that needs to take payments through iTunes.

Comment: Are you wondering how you get paid or how to implement In-app-purchase?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to read In-App purchase programming guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: i want steps for that i have lots of material  for that see this link 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161770/help-need-example-payment-application-for-iphone